# Rounding down numbers to the next lower .95

Tags: python, numbers, rounding

I want to round a number to the next lower .95:

```
20.84 -> 19.95
31.40 -> 30.95
45.34 _> 44.95
57.47 -> 56.95
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since it is easy to round down to the next integer, you can do it like this:

1. add 0.05
2. round down to the next integer
3. subtract 0.05 again

Step 1 is necessary to avoid converting e.g. 2.98 to 1.95.

In Python code:

```
def round_down_95(x):
    return int(x + 0.05) - 0.05
```